# How to estimate a value for IC capacitance in a I2C bus?

Tags: i2c, capacitance

What is a reasonable value to use as the capacitance a I2C device adds to a bus if so is not stated in the datasheet?

With this value I intend on calculating the pull-up resistors to eventually use in a PCB.

I need to append to the bus the following devices:

[L3G4200D gyroscope](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00265057.pdf)

[LIS331DLH accelerometer](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00213470.pdf)

[HMC5883L compass](http://www51.honeywell.com/aero/common/documents/myaerospacecatalog-documents/Defense_Brochures-documents/HMC5883L_3-Axis_Digital_Compass_IC.pdf)

Comment: What is the device? I am amazed that it would not tell you the SDA / SCL load capacitances. I2C specifies no more than a total load of 400pF across the entire bus, so you could design around that.

Comment: 3 devices, actually:
L3G4200D gyroscope, LIS331DLH accelerometer and a HMC5883L compass, and the only thing said about it in any of the datasheets are 2 2k2 pull-up resistors added in the compass application notes...

Comment: And not one tells you its load capacitance? Please put links to the datasheets in the original question text.

Comment: That's actually my second question around here, só I appreciate any more tips to write better :) Thanks!

Comment: I will tell you what I would do. In practice. I would use 2.2k pullups on I2C and then check it during bring-up.

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the three of those datasheets give any details on data line capacitive loading, design around a total bus capacitance of 400pF (the maximum allowed within the [I2C spec](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10216.pdf)). Obviously, once you have a prototype PCB up, use a scope to check the signal waveforms and adjust the pullups appropriately.